# AngularJS invalid or valid error message

Tags: angularjs, validation

I create an AngularJS App without **< form >**. But there is input field.

One of my input field is number.

```
<input type="number" class="input numberfield" placeholder="0" ng-change="changePrice()" ng-model="price" ng-pattern="/^(\d)+$/" name="price" required />
```

Now how I show the error message without from name?

```
<input type="number" class="input numberfield" placeholder="0" ng-change="changePrice()" ng-model="price" ng-pattern="/^(\d)+$/" name="price" required />
<span class="red" ng-show="price.$error.pattern">The price must be given in number format!</span>
```

When I type some any character inside the field, it show  **ng-invalid ng-invalid-number** tag in input class (screenshot 1). When type some number it's show **ng-valid** class (screenshot 2). So my code is works.

But problem is that my error message does not work.

I follow this tutorial: **http://codepen.io/astockwell/pen/JyCva**

But I don't have **form** tag

[image: screenshot 1 - ng-invalid-number]

### **[screenshot 1 - ng-invalid-number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hpYa.png)**

[image: screenshot 2 - ng-valid-number]

### **[screenshot 2 - ng-valid-number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndfhN.png)**

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a form tag.

Angular's validations only work when you have a form tag. You already know your problem is that you don't have a form tag, so add one.

If you *can't* add a form tag (like there's already some parent form tag somewhere), use `ng-form` instead, since you can nest those.

Comment: I added from tag and also added : 

fromname.price.$error.number insert of price.$error.pattern